# selectinput changes but no reaction from the ouput

Tags: shiny, leaflet

Good Evening,

the code i m using is very simple

**UI:**

```
   selectInput("var", label = h4("choose a place"), choices =       c("",as.character(Places$Adr)), selected = "", width = "90%")),
    mainPanel(leafletOutput("mymap"),tableOutput("table"))
```

**Server:**

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

      leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
        #addCircles(lng = as.numeric(Places$Long), lat = as.numeric(Places$Lat), weight = 1) }
```

but when i choose an element from the liste the output (mymap) does'nt change !!
shall i use an obsereEvent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UI widget is not being used by your server.

In UI you named your `selectInput` with the name `"var"`. To use the value from this widget you need to refer to `input$var` in your server.

Comment: I can not answer your question without more information. Please edit your question to include: (1) a description of the desired behavior, (2) a minimal reproducible example.